# Multiple headers message using Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

How to create a instance of Message with multiple headers using Spring Integration MessageBuilder class

Found the below information but it is only for single header

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-integration/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/messaging-construction-chapter.html

Answer (score 0):

Please use the [current documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-construction-chapter.html) - your link is not even to a released version, but a milestone of the 3.0.0 release. The current version is 4.2.0.RELEASE.

You can add as many headers as you want...

```
Message<String> message4 = MessageBuilder.withPayload("test4")
    .setHeader("foo", 123)
    .setHeader("bar", 456)
    .build();
```

Comment: Thank you. Yeah I do follow the current documentation the above link was for just representation purpose as the examples were same in both version.

Comment: @Gary If we explicitly change MessageHeaders.ID in Map?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. And you should not ask new questions in comments on old answers (especially those that are as old as this one). Ask a new question with much more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use createMessage method. Pass MessageHeaders as second argument.

```
Map<String,Object> headers = new HashMap<>();

    headers.put("foo", 123);
    headers.put("bar", 456);

    MessageBuilder.createMessage(payload, new MessageHeaders(headers));
```